# value foreach is not a member of Int?

Tags: scala

I am learning scala, and I need to print powers of 2 with its reciprocal from 0 to 20

What I am doing is

```
scala> for {
     | i <- 0 to 20
     | pow <- scala.math.pow(2, i).toInt
     | rec <- 1/pow
     | } println(pow + "\t" + rec)
```

But I see error as

```
<console>:13: error: value foreach is not a member of Int
       pow <- scala.math.pow(2, i).toInt
                                   ^
```

I know `pow` is not iterable, but how can I compute it before so that I reuse it?

Else, I am recomputing it as

```
scala> for(i <- 0 to 10) println(scala.math.pow(2, i).toInt + "\t" + 1/scala.math.pow(2,i))
1   1.0
2   0.5
4   0.25
8   0.125
16  0.0625
32  0.03125
64  0.015625
128 0.0078125
256 0.00390625
512 0.001953125
1024    9.765625E-4
```

Ugly, right?

Answer (score 9):

When you use `<-` in a for comprehension, you need to be providing a type compatible with the output of the first such `<-`. Here, you create a `Seq[Int]` from the line `i <- 0 to 20`, but then an `Int` from the next line. Instead, you can just assign the intermediate results, and yield a list at the end (that you can then print out or otherwise work with as you choose).

Also, you should note that by casting to an `Int` where you do, you ensure the reciprocal is calculated using integer division, which results in zero for the reciprocal for all but the first power - do the casting to `Int` in the yield so you have `Double` reciprocals.

Overall:

```
val result = for {
     i <- 0 to 20
     pow = scala.math.pow(2, i)
     rec = 1/pow
} yield (pow.toInt + "\t" + rec)
```

You can then print out the results using something like:

```
println(result.mkString("\n"))
```

Output will then be something like:

```
1   1.0
2   0.5
4   0.25
8   0.125
16  0.0625
32  0.03125
64  0.015625
128 0.0078125
256 0.00390625
512 0.001953125
1024    9.765625E-4
2048    4.8828125E-4
4096    2.44140625E-4
8192    1.220703125E-4
16384   6.103515625E-5
32768   3.0517578125E-5
65536   1.52587890625E-5
131072  7.62939453125E-6
262144  3.814697265625E-6
524288  1.9073486328125E-6
1048576 9.5367431640625E-7
```

Further, you could alter the yield to generate a list of tuples, then format however you choose later (decoupling formatting from generation):

```
val result = { ... // as before
} yield (i, pow, rec) // Could prove handy to keep the index, and keep pow as a Double for now

def printResults(results: List[(Int, Double, Double)], formatter: (Int, Double, Double) => String) = results forEach { case (n, pow, rec) =>
  println(formatter(n, pow, rec))
}

def egFormatter(n: Int, pow: Double, rec: Double) = s"For n = $n,\t 2^n = ${pow.toInt},\t reciprocal = $rec"

printResults(results, egFormatter)
```

Answer (score 2):

A rather different approach, using `Streams`, offers some flexibility (length of output is chosen by the caller instead of being hard-coded) and memoization (after a value has been calculated it can then be retrieved rather than re-calculated).

```
// pts --> Powers of Two Stream
val pts: Stream[(Int,Double)] = (1,1.0) #:: fs.zipWithIndex.map{x=>
                                   val p = scala.math.pow(2, x._2+1);
                                   (p.toInt, 1/p)}

scala> pts.take(20).mkString("\n")
res11: String =
(1,1.0)
(2,0.5)
(4,0.25)
(8,0.125)
(16,0.0625)
(32,0.03125)
(64,0.015625)
(128,0.0078125)
(256,0.00390625)
(512,0.001953125)
(1024,9.765625E-4)
(2048,4.8828125E-4)
(4096,2.44140625E-4)
(8192,1.220703125E-4)
(16384,6.103515625E-5)
(32768,3.0517578125E-5)
(65536,1.52587890625E-5)
(131072,7.62939453125E-6)
(262144,3.814697265625E-6)
(524288,1.9073486328125E-6)
```

Output formatting is left as an exercise for the reader.